# Inserting json object into MongoDB using mongolite R package

Tags: json, r, mongodb, mongolite

There are quite a few packages for dealing with MongoDB in R. I started using 'mongolite' package,  because I work with 'jsonlite' and 'mongolite' builds on top of 'jsonlite'. However, I'm a bit puzzled, why insert function in 'mongolite' does not allow to insert json objects (help says it inserts dataframes)?

What package should I use to store json objects and do simple queries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `jsonlite` you can still use `mongolite` to insert your data, but **only if** it can also be coerced to a `data.frame` (using `fromJSON`). For example:

```
js <- '[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "val": "a"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "val": "b"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "val": "c"
  }
] '


library(jsonlite)
library(mongolite)

mongo <- mongo(collection = "test", db = "test", url = "mongodb://localhost",
      verbose = TRUE)

mongo$insert(fromJSON(js))
# Complete! Processed total of 3 rows.
# [1] TRUE
```

---

However, my understanding is that the `mongolite` package will **only** insert `data.frames`. For example, taking a more complicated `JSON` structure you'll see we can't insert it using `mongolite`

```
js <- '{"foo":[{"id":1,"val":"a"},{"id":2,"val":"b"},{"id":3,"val":"c"}],"bar":[[{"id":1,"val":"a"},{"id":2,"val":"b"},{"id":3,"val":"c"}]]}'

## if we try to insert this using mongolite we get an error
## because it is not a data.frame
> mongo$insert(fromJSON(js))
Error: is.data.frame(data) is not TRUE
```

---

To insert a more complicated `JSON` structure we can use the `mongo.bson.from.json` function from the `rmongodb` package

```
library(rmongodb)
mongo <- mongo.create()
mongo.is.connected(mongo)
# [1] TRUE

db <- "test"
coll <- "test"

bs <- mongo.bson.from.JSON(js)

mongo.insert(mongo, ns = paste0(db ,".", coll), b = bs)
# [1] TRUE
```

Taking note that `mongodb` actually stores **BSON**:

> MongoDB represents JSON documents in binary-encoded format called BSON behind the scenes. BSON extends the JSON model to provide additional data types and to be efficient for encoding and decoding within different languages

Reference: [JSON and BSON](https://www.mongodb.com/json-and-bson)

Comment: Unfortunately, rmongodb is not available on CRAN anymore. But how would your example list would be loaded anyway ? As two documents "foo" and "bar", or as one massive document ? In the latter case, using [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) on the command line would do the trick.

Comment: @paulwasit `rmongodb` was very useful for this type of insert. It's a shame it's not being supported - hopefully someone will take it over. Or, perhaps a feature-request should be submitted to `mongolite` so it can insert more complex structures.

Answer (score 1):

The development version of mongolite now supports inserting nested lists or json directly, see https://github.com/jeroenooms/mongolite/issues/42

You can also query and get back a nested list using `m$iterate()` or `m$iterate()$batch()`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up; will start having a play with the development version